# Standard SSL to protect multiple subdomains

Tags: ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain(GoDaddy), say example.com and standard SSL certificate to protect it. The combo works fine to setup a secured website hosted in Apache2 at https://www.example.com

Can the same SSL certificate be used for more subdomains like https://api.example.com and https://learn.example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SSL certificate can only secure single domain name for example example.com but it can secure **api.example.com**, **learn.example.com** but for that you will have to purchase separate standard SSL certificate for each sub domain.

So in this case [Wildcard SSL](https://www.clickssl.net/cheapest-wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-sub-domains) certificate will remain the best option to secure first level of unlimited sub domains of the main domain name (**example.com**) like **api.example.com**, **learn.example.com**,**payment.example.com** etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect multiple sub domains like  https://api.example.com and https://learn.example.com, you need a [wildcard SSL Certificate](https://comodosslstore.com/ssl-types/wildcard) which can cover unlimited number of sub domains.

Additionally, if you want to protect both multiple domains or sub domains, you can use [multi domain wildcard SSL](https://comodosslstore.com/ssl-types/multi-domain-wildcard) Certificate.